# List of all identity columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus, identity-column

How do you get a list of all identity columns in Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 3):

SELECT table_name, column_name
  FROM all_tab_columns
WHERE identity_column = 'YES';

Answer (score 2):

Query [USER|ALL|DBA|CDB_TAB_IDENTITY_COLS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/ALL_TAB_IDENTITY_COLS.html) for technical details about the  identity settings.

Query [USER|ALL|DBA|CDB_TAB_COLUMNS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.html) where `IDENTITY_COLUMN = 'YES'` as suggested in [Prasanth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58635783/230471) for general information about the columns.

Answer (score 1):

select * from user_tab_identity_cols;

Answer (score -4):

There are no identity columns in Oracle as in SQL server. There is a concept of Primary Key in Oracle. You can find list of primary keys for all tables in DB using below query:

```
SELECT a.table_name,a.column_name
FROM all_cons_columns a, all_constraints b
where a.constraint_name = b.constraint_name
and b.constraint_type = 'P';
```

Hope this helps:)

Comment: Oracle 12C have introduced the Identity column.